# Hyundai Elantra HD model 2008 and BWS

Tags: hyundai, elantra

I owner Hyundai elantra HD model 2008. I want to install BWS (backup warning system). I already purchased a supervision speedometer dashboard and BWS module, rear bumper and everything related it

I have been succeeded with connect bws and it is works right now with beep sound while reverse without any issue, but I left one thing and it is how displaying it on supervision speedometer

You can see a pic below from function I want showing it on dashboard tidy

https://ibb.co/8ddG0kr

I hope to help me please how I can connect it, can you provide me a wiring diagram

Thank you in advanced

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm not sure what a "supervision speedometer" is? Also, if you purchased this stuff, didn't it come with any instructions? Is this aftermarket or Hyundai specific?

Comment: SuperVision is speedometer come with Korean Avante HD model

Comment: Please see the attachment, It is like that: https://ibb.co/8ddG0kr